# Calculate the duration from a date time column using pandas groupby or any other pandas function

Tags: python, pandas

I am new in pandas, I have dataframe as shown below

1. How to calculate the durations in days for a particular 'ID' from first status to next status and so on.
2. Count how many IDs having more than two failure with at least one maintenance in between them .
3. Subset the data with Failure-Failure pattern and Failure-Maintenance.

I tried all combinations pandas groupby functions such as

```
df.groupby(['ID', 'Status' ]).size().reset_index(name='counts').sort_values(['counts'], ascending =False)
```

Created the DF using following dictionary

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

sales = [ {'ID': '1', 'Status': 'Failure', 'Date': '2017-04-26'},

         {'ID': '2', 'Status': 'Failure', 'Date': '2017-05-06'},

         {'ID': '1', 'Status': 'Maintenance', 'Date': '2017-05-16'},

        {'ID': '1', 'Status': 'Failure', 'Date': '2017-07-06'},

         {'ID': '2', 'Status': 'Failure', 'Date': '2017-09-06'},

         {'ID': '1', 'Status': 'Failure', 'Date': '2018-01-14'},

         {'ID': '3', 'Status': 'Maintenance', 'Date': '2017-07-16'},

         {'ID': '4', 'Status': 'Failure', 'Date': '2017-07-16'},

         {'ID': '2', 'Status': 'Maintenance', 'Date': '2018-07-06'},

         {'ID': '3', 'Status': 'Failure', 'Date': '2018-01-06'},

         {'ID': '3', 'Status': 'Maintenance', 'Date': '2018-07-06'},

         {'ID': '3', 'Status': 'Failure', 'Date': '2019-07-06'},

        {'ID': '2', 'Status': 'Maintenance', 'Date': '2019-05-06'},

        {'ID': '2', 'Status': 'Failure', 'Date': '2019-10-06'},

        {'ID': '4', 'Status': 'Maintenance', 'Date': '2019-11-06'}]

df = pd.DataFrame(sales)

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

Expected out put

1. for ID1 - first status is failure - on 2017-04-26 and second status is Maintenance on 2017-05-16 so the duration (days taken from first status to second status)  is 19 days  (not inclusive of both days) and third status is failure on 2017-07-06 and the duration is  70 days(4 days in April, 31 days in May, 30 days in June and 5 days in July).

2.1 How many IDs having more than one failure.

2.1 How many IDs having more than one failure with one Maintenance in between them. and how many with two maintenance in between failure and so on.

3. Subset the data with Failure-Failure pattern . Failure-Maintenance.

Explanation about the problem 3 as given below
after sorting the dataframe based on 'ID' and 'Date' we get below dataframe

```
      Date     ID  Status
0   2017-04-26  1   F
2   2017-05-16  1   M
3   2017-07-06  1   F
5   2018-01-14  1   F
1   2017-05-06  2   F
4   2017-09-06  2   F
8   2018-07-06  2   M
12  2019-05-06  2   M
13  2019-10-06  2   F
6   2017-07-16  3   M
9   2018-01-06  3   F
10  2018-07-06  3   M
11  2019-07-06  3   F
7   2017-07-16  4   F
14  2019-11-06  4   M
```

now in ID 1, index 3 and 5 is F-F, in ID 2 index 1 and 4 is F-F in ID 3, there is no F-F pattern and also in ID 4, there is no F-F pattern.

So the expected F-F subset is given below.

```
      Date     ID  Status
0   2017-07-06  1   F
1   2018-01-14  1   F
2   2017-05-06  2   F
3   2017-09-06  2   F
```

Similarly the F-M dataframe after subsetting is give below

```
       Date    ID   Status
0   2017-04-26  1   F
1   2017-05-16  1   M
2   2017-09-06  2   F
3   2018-07-06  2   M
4   2018-01-06  3   F
5   2018-07-06  3   M
6   2017-07-16  4   F
7   2019-11-06  4   M
```

Comment: Expected out put 

1. for ID1 - first status is failure - on 2017-04-26 and second status is Maintenance on 2017-05-16 so the duration (days taken from first status to second status)  is 19 days  (not inclusive of both days) and third status is failure on 2017-07-06 and the duration is  70 days(4 days in April, 31 days in May, 30 days in June and 5 days in July).

2nd out put expected - 

How many IDs having more than two failure with in between at least one maintenance

Comment: Can we convert the out put into dataframe, I thought about that I did not get any idea.
1 - Failure - 19 - Maintenance - 70 - Failure

That means for ID - 1 first failure then after 19 days Maintenance then after 70 days Maintenance

Comment: @anky_91 ID1 - Failure - 19 - Maintenance - 70 - Failure and so on for all IDs

Comment: can you not just post the expected output dataframe? anyway-may be  like you posted an input df, same way for output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see hard to understand your questions but maybe these answers can help you completely solve it or at least not get stuck (in case I got questions wrong)

I still see **three** questions:

> Calculate the durations in days for a particular 'ID' for next failure and next any status.
>
> Count how many IDs having more than two failure.
>
> how many have at least one maintenance in between them

---

Since you need pandas and Numpy

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

    sales = [{'ID': '1', 'Status': 'Failure', 'Date': '2017-04-26'},
             {'ID': '2', 'Status': 'Failure', 'Date': '2017-05-06'},
             {'ID': '1', 'Status': 'Maintenance', 'Date': '2017-05-16'},
             {'ID': '1', 'Status': 'Failure', 'Date': '2017-07-06'},
             {'ID': '2', 'Status': 'Failure', 'Date': '2017-09-06'},
             {'ID': '1', 'Status': 'Failure', 'Date': '2018-01-14'},
             {'ID': '3', 'Status': 'Maintenance', 'Date': '2017-07-16'},
             {'ID': '4', 'Status': 'Failure', 'Date': '2017-07-16'},
             {'ID': '2', 'Status': 'Maintenance', 'Date': '2018-07-06'},
             {'ID': '3', 'Status': 'Failure', 'Date': '2018-01-06'},
             {'ID': '3', 'Status': 'Maintenance', 'Date': '2018-07-06'},
             {'ID': '3', 'Status': 'Failure', 'Date': '2019-07-06'},
             {'ID': '2', 'Status': 'Maintenance', 'Date': '2019-05-06'},
             {'ID': '2', 'Status': 'Failure', 'Date': '2019-10-06'},
             {'ID': '4', 'Status': 'Maintenance', 'Date': '2019-11-06'}]

    df = pd.DataFrame(sales)
    df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
    df = df.sort_values(['ID', 'Date', 'Status'])

    print('{0}\n'.format(df))

    # Question 2
    # IDs with more than two failures
    df_question2 = df.groupby(['ID', 'Status']) \
        .size().reset_index() \
        .rename(columns={'ID': 'ID', 'Status': 'Status', 0: 'Counts'})

    # Answer 2
    counts_of_more_than_two_failures = len(df_question2.loc[df_question2['Counts'] > 2])
    print('IDs with more than two failures : {0}'.format(counts_of_more_than_two_failures))

    # Question 3
    # one maintenance between failures
    df_question3 = df
    df_question3['Status'] = np.where(df['Status'] == 'Failure', '1', '0')

    df_question3_status = df_question3.groupby('ID')['Status'].apply(list)
    dict_question3 = df_question3_status.to_frame().to_dict().get('Status')

    # Answer 3
    for key, value in dict_question3.items():
        # keep only non-empty values from the list
        _find_me = list(filter(None, ''.join(value).strip('0').split('1')))
        _has = True if _find_me else False
        print('ID {0} has number of maintenance between failures: {1}'.format(key, _has))

    print('\n')

    # subset patterns
    df = pd.DataFrame(sales)
    df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
    df = df.sort_values(['ID', 'Date', 'Status'])
    df_question3 = df
    df_question3['Status'] = np.where(df['Status'] == 'Failure', '0', '1')

    df_question3_patterns = df_question3.groupby('ID')['Status'].apply(list)
    dict_question3 = df_question3_patterns.to_frame().to_dict().get('Status')

    # F-F
    # temp dataframe
    df_ff_pattern = pd.DataFrame([])
    for k, value in enumerate(dict_question3.items()):
        # keep index in dictionary values
        for i, j in enumerate(value[1]):
            # only FF values
            if i < len(value[1]) - 1 and j == '0':
                if value[1][i] == value[1][i + 1]:
                    # locate n and n+1 rows based on i index
                    df_ff_pattern = df_ff_pattern.append(df_question3[df_question3['ID'] == value[0]].iloc[[i, i + 1]])

    print('subset FF patterns')
    # back-substitute status values
    df_ff_pattern['Status'] = np.where(df_ff_pattern['Status'] == '0', 'F', 'M')
    print(df_ff_pattern)

    print('\n')

    # F-M
    for k, value in enumerate(dict_question3.items()):
        # keep index in dictionary values
        for i, j in enumerate(value[1]):
            # only FM values
            if i < len(value[1])-1 and j == '0':
                if value[1][i] != value[1][i + 1]:
                    # locate n and n+1 rows based on i index
                    print('subset FM patterns')
                    print(df_question3[df_question3['ID'] == value[0]].iloc[[i, i+1]])

    # Question 1
    df_question1 = pd.DataFrame(sales)
    df_question1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_question1['Date'])
    df_question1 = df_question1.reset_index().sort_values(['ID', 'Date', 'Status']).set_index(['ID', 'Status'])
    df_question1['Difference'] = df_question1.groupby('ID')['Date'].transform(pd.Series.diff)

    # Possible Answer 1
    # all days in statuses
    print(df_question1)

    df_question1 = df_question1.reset_index()
    df_question1_failure = df_question1.loc[df_question1['Status'] == 'Failure']
    df_question1_failure_pre_diff = df_question1_failure[['ID', 'Difference']]

    # filter by status
    df_question1_maintenance = df_question1.loc[df_question1['Status'] == 'Maintenance']
    df_question1_maintenance_pre_diff = df_question1_maintenance[['ID', 'Difference']]

    # group by and sum
    df_question1_failure_group = df_question1_failure_pre_diff.groupby('ID').sum()
    df_question1_maintenance_group = df_question1_maintenance_pre_diff.groupby('ID').sum()

    # Possible Answer 1
    # days in status failure
    print((df_question1_failure_group - df_question1_maintenance_group).abs())
```

If you think something is missing, please, comment and the answer can be improved.
Anyway, if someone else got them right, this may become just a start point

Hope it helps (:

Comment: Thank you so much,  following lines of code is seems to be not working    for key, value in dict_question3.items():
    _has = '0' in ''.join(value).strip('0').split('1')
    print('ID {0} has number of maintenance between failures: {1}'.format(key, _has))

Comment: you're welcome, pal. if you need that two maintenance values between failure values also count, that's slightly different requirement, but I can update the answer accordingly. right now, if only 1 maintenance is between 2 failures, then 2 maintenance between failures don't satisfy the requirement because one of maintenance already surround the other. F-M-F is fine. But F-M-M-F is not since you have either F-M-M or M-M-F -unless you change the requirement. If so, please, let me know and I update the answer (:

Comment: out of IDs having more than one failure, I also trying to find how many IDs having 1 maintenance in between them, 2 maintenance between them and so on.

Comment: Sure, dude! updated. something else, let me know (:

Comment: Thanks dude, I am also trying to subset this dataframe into F-F, F-M, M-F and M-M, is it possible to subset this dataframe

Comment: For Pandas almost anything is possible. Just kindly show an output of what you want to get and add it

Comment: I just updated my doubts (edited the above one). please check.. I am not sure about my explanation. If it is not clear please feel free to ask me about clarifying that.

Comment: added, kindly look into that your feedback is highly appreciated.

Comment: I want all F-F pattern into one dataFrame, is it possible to get that?